# What is returned by this operator overloading function?

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, square-bracket

I have the following listing from a page:

```
#include "vector.h"

// An axis-aligned bounding box
class AABB
{
  public:
    VECTOR P; //position
    VECTOR E; //x,y,z extents

    AABB( const VECTOR& p, const VECTOR& e): P(p) ,E(e) {}

    // ...

    const SCALAR min( long i ) const
    {

      return ((AABB*)this)->P[i] - ((AABB*)this)->E[i];
    }
    // ...
};
```

Now what I don't understand is, what is accessed by min() with a long value.
I've looked into `vector.h`and found out that the square-bracket operator is overloaded:

```
class VECTOR
{
  public:
    SCALAR x,y,z; //x,y,z coordinates

    //...

    //index a component
    //NOTE: returning a reference allows
    //you to assign the indexed element
    SCALAR& operator [] ( const long i )
    {
      return *((&x) + i);
    }
    //...
};
```

Later it is used as:

```
// each axis
for( long i=0 ; i<3 ; i++ )
{
  if( A.max(i)<B.min(i) && v[i]<0 )
  {
```

So why is the `x` value reference incremented by `i`?
Please bear with me if this question is ridiculous easy, I am still a rookie. And if this isn't enough of information, I can provide the actual source

Comment: `(AABB*)this`? `(&x) + i`? What the...run away from this code.

Comment: Yeah, my reaction was the same :)

Comment: This code (which is a good example of doing things the wrong way) is working hard to access the scalar values (i.e., _x_, _y_, _z_) as an array.  In particular, the `operator [] ( const long i )` uses the address of x (`&x`), along with the index (`i`) to find the memory address of the respective element, and return its value.

Comment: This code yields undefined behaviour, padding might lead to holes between the field values. Don't do it like this or yell at the programmer who wrote it.

Comment: it may just be me, but I don't understand what your question is. Why is the `x` reference incremented by `i`? because `i` is used to choose which `x`,`y`, or `z` to be returned. Is that your question?

Comment: @GManNickG Yeah I will run as fast as I can. It's from a veeery old tutorial. But it's more about the maths behind it.

Comment: @TaylorFlores Sorry I couldn't describe it very well, but people seem to get what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not incremented.

```
&x  //<- address of member x
(&x) + i //<- address of member x shifted right by i SCALAR's
*((&x) + i) // the scalar value at that point
```

Hence `*((&x) + i)` returns the i'th scalar. x for 0, y for 1, z for 2.

Comment: Thanks. you were first so here's your green badge

Answer (score 3):

This is called pointer arithmetic.

In the code, `&x` takes the address of `x` which is a pointer; adding `i` to that means that the pointer is incremented by `sizeof(x) * i`. Usually you do this to achieve the same effect as indexing into an array. For example, if you have

```
int arr[10];
```

then by writing `&arr[0] + i` you effectively index to the `i`th integer in the array. In some cases there might be some other type of contiguous memory block instead of a standard array.

This is not quite what happens in the case under question, because there is no array or other such memory block here. Instead the code assumes that the compiler will calculate a memory layout for `VECTOR` such that `x`, `y`, and `z` would be placed alongside in memory, simulating an array layout.

However this practice invokes undefined behavior according to C++ standard, so this implementation of `VECTOR` is flawed and should not be used.

Comment: @GManNickG: It would be UB even with a guarantee because of technically indexing out of bounds, right?

Comment: Just something to add: The reason this behavior is undefined is because compilers will sometimes change the spacing, or even the order, of variables in the data segment to improve performance - this is called memory alignment. It changes especially on machines with different address spaces.

Comment: @Jon: Yup, good point.  All we're guaranteed is `&x < &y < &z` (where `<` has absolute ordering, like `std::less<void*>()`). If we use compiler-specific magic to ensure they are next to each other (which once true is, as far as I know, still outside of the cares of C++), then it's not *unreasonable* to treat it as `int xyz[3]`, with `&x` `&xyz[0]`. But it's certainly not guaranteed; it's just that once you use compiler magic you are generally entitled to also use more compiler magic (though we should avoid magic when not needed, like here).

Comment: @TaylorFlores: Actually inside a `struct` which is just an alias for `class` in C++, the order of members is guaranteed to follow the order of declaration. Back when C was created it was common to write structs directly into files or onto the network so you would not want an optimizer moving members around.

Comment: @ZanLynx, good to know. Does the same go for padding? Is there no padding withing a `struct`?

Comment: @TaylorFlores: Nope. Padding came later I think. C compilers are allowed to add padding where they like it. However, it cannot be random padding. The compiler has to do it the same way each time it compiles. This still allows binary serialization to work.

Answer (score 2):

The operation being done in `operator[]` is "pointer arithmetic" - where you use normal arithmetic operators (`+` in this case) to navigate memory using a pointer (generally with arrays).

You can see some more examples of this technique here:
http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html

It should be noted that, if `SCALAR` is some non-array type, then I would argue that **the code given is "dangerous"**, in that it assumes that `x`, `y` and `z` are going to be in adjacent memory locations, which is not guaranteed by standard C++. The result would be, if you try to use this code on a platform that doesn't guarantee this assumption, is that `operator[]` would at best return some undefined value, or at worst cause a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

That's pointer arithmetic.

In the `VECTOR` struct, the `SCALAR` members will **likely** (It's not guaranteed.) appear consecutively in memory, and the author of that code took advantage of that by just adding an index to the memory address of the first member in the struct (`x`).

This is how the input maps to the output:

- `0` ... `*(&x + 0)` ... `x`
- `1` ... `*(&x + 1)` ... `y`
- `2` ... `*(&x + 2)` ... `z`

This was a pretty unsafe assumption by the author however :V.
(Padding bytes, order of members, etc...)

Comment: It's an article from October 18, 1999 :)

Comment: That explains it. I suspected the snippet was pretty old :P